# Linker Error: Undefined reference / bad reloc address / ld returned 1 exit

Tags: c++, constructor, reference, linker, undefined

I am relatively new to programming especially object-oriented languages. I have class Player and am trying to use simple math functions in main to test. I noticed linker errors but ignored them until I got further in my function calling statements and now I'm a bit lost on where to look. I think I am misunderstanding overlapping constructors / constructors in general...

#### This is my error:

```
*C:\Users\Nytza\AppData\Local\Temp\ccRUivW8.o   ootest.cpp:(.text+0x272): undefined reference to `Player::Player(char const*, int, int, int)'

C:\Users\Nytza\AppData\Local\Temp\ccRUivW8.o    ootest.cpp:(.text+0x27e): undefined reference to `Player::Player()'

C:\Users\Nytza\AppData\Local\Temp\ccRUivW8.o    ootest.cpp:(.text+0x2a5): undefined reference to `Player::Player(char const*, int, int, int)'

C:\Users\Nytza\AppData\Local\Temp\ccRUivW8.o    ootest.cpp:(.text+0x2cc): undefined reference to `Player::Player(char const*, int, int, int)'

C:\Users\Nytza\AppData\Local\Temp\ccRUivW8.o    ootest.cpp:(.text+0x2f6): undefined reference to `Player::Player(char const*, int, int, int)'

C:\Users\Nytza\AppData\Local\Temp\ccRUivW8.o    ootest.cpp:(.text+0x320): undefined reference to `Player::Player(char const*, int, int, int)'

c:\program files (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\bin\ld.exe    C:\Users\Nytza\AppData\Local\Temp\ccRUivW8.o: bad reloc address 0x0 in section `.pdata$_ZStanSt13_Ios_FmtflagsS_'

D:\Documents\Programs\collect2.exe  [Error] ld returned 1 exit status*
```

### includes / Player class

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

class Player
{
    public:
      Player();
      Player( const char [], int, int, int );

      void printPlayer();
      void printPlayer(const char[], int, int, int);

      void setName();
      void setName( const char [] );
      void changeGoals( int );
      void changeAssists( int );
      void changeRating( int );

      int getGoals();
      int getAssists();
      int getRating();

    private:
      char name[50];
      int goals;
      int assists;
      int rating;
};
```

The errors start after adding these lines in main:

### int main()

```
int main()
{
    Player p1 ("Nytza Delirosa", 1, 1, 1);
    Player p2;
    Player p3 ("Jonathan Toews", 10, 9, 6);
    Player p4 ("Patrick Kane", 11, 10, -3);
    Player p5 ("Brandon Saad", 5, 8, 8);
    Player p6 ("Andrew Shaw", 6, 5, 6);

...
    return 0;
}
```

### All my functions:

```
void Player::printPlayer()
{   
    int points = getGoals() + getAssists();
    cout  << name << endl <<
        "Goals: " << goals <<
        "Assists: " << assists <<
        "Points: " << points <<
        "Plus/Minus: " << showpos << rating << noshowpos << endl << endl;
}

void Player::setName()
{
    name[0] = '\0';
}

void Player::setName( const char playerName[] )
{
    strcpy(name, playerName);
}

void Player::changeGoals( int goalsScored )
{
    if (goalsScored < 0 )
        cout << "Error: Not at least 0 goals.";
    else goals++;
}

void Player::changeAssists( int assistsEarned )
{
    if (assistsEarned < 0 )
        cout << "Error: Not at least 0 assists.";
    else assists=+assistsEarned;
}

int Player::getGoals()
{
    return goals;
}

int Player::getAssists()
{
    return assists;
}

int Player::getRating()
{
    return rating;
}
```

Comment: Why not use string instead of char[]?

Comment: Do you have Player.cpp file with implementation of `Player` functions including constructors? Is it included in the build?

Comment: A string would be easier, but the purpose of this program isn't ease or efficiency but just a testing stage. a char gave me problems initially but I didn't want to just use a string. 

I'm using TDM-GCC 4.8.1 64 bit.

Comment: It is a single .cpp. Main is at the bottom, so i do not have prototypes set.

Comment: @Nytza can you maybe show us how you defined those functions in the *.cpp file?

Comment: @PeterT added my functions

Comment: @Nytza ok, but where did you define the constructors (which I actually meant, I should have been more clear)?

Comment: @PeterT Sorry, I'm a tad confused here. This is literally all my code, so I think I'm missing something. o.o

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently you didn't define the constructors for `Player`:

```
Player();
Player( const char [], int, int, int );
```

Add at least stub definitions like this:

```
Player::Player() 
{
}

Player::Player( const char [], int, int, int )
{
}
```